# External Email Server for one domain under cPanel server

Tags: cpanel

Trying to set up a domain name under cPanel server... so far so good, the problem comes once I am trying to point this domain to an external Kerio Mail server.
Even though from ssh user root can telnet the Kerio Mail server, when the user/domain tries to sent email using this server, get's smtp connection timed out.

Wondering is there's more than DNS changes that need to be made or something else is needed in cPanel firewall (CSF)
To allow SMTP connection to another server, any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send mail from your server and getting timeout then you need to check your firewall. First I will suggest you please try to disable your server firewall and test your mail again.